# How to test asynchronous method results?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

When we get table view datasource, we will ask a network request. It is asynchronous. I have no idea to test the result operation. There is a method to get the points.

```
     func loadPoints() {
        API().retrievePoints{ [weak self](pointsSet, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                // Make sure the call succeeded; return an error if it didn't
                guard error == nil else {
                    self?.showErrorMessage()
                    Device.debugLog(item:"Error loading Points: \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }

                self?.pointsSet = pointsSet
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
```

I have known that if we want to test the retrievePoints method, we can test like bellow

```
//points
func testRetrievePoints() {
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "RetrievePoints")
    API().retrievePoints{ (pointsSet, error) -> Void in
        XCTAssertNil(pointsSet)
        XCTAssertNotNil(error)
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 15.0, handler: nil)
}
```

Now I want to test the codes

```
         self?.pointsSet = pointsSet
         self?.tableView.reloadData()

         self?.showErrorMessage()
```

For now I just use sleep(15) to wait the method. But it is inaccurate.
Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just as what you have said, it's asynchronous. So it will take time before finish. That is to say that you need to wait before it can success.
Also note that it's just timeout value. All your task must finish within this value. Or it will be treated as failure.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test your data source — not your web service. 
there for you should mock the api call.

To achieve this you could use a mocking framework. But I'd rather go another route:

1. create a protocol that declares the public interface of `API`, let `API` conform to that protocol
2. pass the `API` as a dependency into the data source. either as an init parameter or via a property. Passing objects is easier that classes, I'd change `retrievePoints` to be an instance method.
3. For your test write an `APIMock` that implements the protocol. Let `retrievePoints`' callback return prepared points.

Now the points will be returned immediately, no need for timeouts. If you want to defer that your mock can use a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` call.

Comment: I have known what you said. And how to mock that testing calling successfully or failed in the retrievePoints method? Save a flag to the UserDefaults when testing?

Comment: tests and mocks are just normal code — either create a mock that you can configure to either fail or succeed. or create 2 mocks. About NSUserDefaults: You should pass (some say: inject) every dependency, including the user defaults. So there is some more to be done. In tests you want to pass in a clean user default object. but that isn't easy to create, as new defaults will be populated with exiting values. What I do here: I create a protocol that contains every method I use on NSUserDefaults. via extension I declare conformance for NSUserDefaults. I pass it typed as the protocol,

Comment: preferably as a default argument. Now I can fully mock the defaults in unit tests.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Inject every dependency. Refer to [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). It's the D in [SOLID Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Comment: The points will be returned immediately by mocking. But the operation will not be performed immediately. The UI operation need to be performed in the main threat.  `self?.pointsSet = pointsSet
         self?.tableView.reloadData() ` They are in the code bellow.                              
         `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { })`  I have no idea to judge when it will be performed.

Comment: The issues you are describing are not related to the question you asked. And without the code I doubt it makes no sense to try to answer them. You should asked a new question and include the codes there.